# What is the difference between processors i5 and i7 of MBP 2020 13 inch?

Tags: macbook-pro, performance

According to geek bench portal there is no significant performance changes:

**Macbook Pro 2020, 13 inch, i7**, 4 June
[image]

**Macbook Pro 2020, 13 inch, i5** 4 June
[image]

**Macbook Pro 2020, 13 inch, i5** 7 May
[image]

**Macbook Pro 2020, 13 inch, i7** 7 May
[image]

What makes the difference between them?

Comment: I've removed the part of your question which only youself can answer :-)

Comment: Have you checked your own data? The second table you list as i7 but is it i5 - is that your error?

Answer (score 0):

Individual Geekbench scores will vary: you need to look at the average (or max score) from a range of users to get a better idea.

The usual difference between i5 and i7 CPUs is that the i7s have [HyperThreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading): 2 virtual cores per actual core. So when you look in Activity Monitor, you will see 8 cores in the CPU Usage window, and process values up to 800%.

However, Intel does make some i5 CPUs that do have HT, just to confuse the branding. (Similarly, i3 CPUs used to have HyperThreading but no TurboBoost until the 9th gen, when TurboBoost was added.)

In short: if the geekbench scores are similar, and the CPUs do have similar characteristics, then there probably isn't much meaningful difference.